# Get full list of secret codes in android

Tags: android, android-activity, adb, app-secret

I was able to run some of the settings hidden apps via ADB with
ADB shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN "com.android.settings"

These hidden apps are actually some of the activities runnable via "secret codes".
Since secret codes are various and some of them are also vendor/device defined, is there a way to retrieve a list of every secret code available on a particular device?
Maybe from a manifest, by identifying the receivers, via some ADB commands, etc.

Thank you in advance!